# How to change button label in a ruby on rails form_for submit button

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a ruby on rails `form_for`, I want to use a button to submit the form rather than a `f.submit`. If the form is for an existing `@profile` object, then the following code

```
<%= form_for @profile do %>
<% f.button submit: 'Change Me' %>
```

is rendered as button with the text 'Update Profile' instead of 'Change Me'. How do I change the button text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<% f.button 'Change Me', type: 'submit' %>
```

Comment: This does not work for me, it makes the text 'submit'. I also tried ```f.button submit: '', value: 'change me'``` and this just gives the text as  'Update Profile'

Comment: @Obromios Sorry, I forgot that it only works with simple_form gem. I updated my answer - should work for you now.

Comment: That now works, thank you. I have accepted your answer rather than mine, as I think it is likely to be more robust to future changes to the ```form_for``` helper.

Comment: @Obromios Did you forget to click the green checkmark below the vote? :)

Answer (score 0):

The following worked

```
<%= form_for @profile do %>
<%= button_tag 'Change Me' %>
```

the reason being that the `form_for` helper automatically treats a button within the scope as a submit.